# Java SHA1 for unicode?

Tags: java, android, unicode, hash, localization

I tried to get a SHA1 hash for a unicode string, some chinese string
in Android Java code in Eclipse. I used the usual MessageDigest class
and some Hex conversion piece of code from web.

I wonder how to verify that the hash and its hex conversion are correct? 
I inserted that chinese string to a number of online hash converters, but 
all of them produced a different hash. The same coverters work fine with
ascii strings.

I am newbie in this, so some pointers would be appreciated!

br, perza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What counts as "correct"? Hashes such as SHA-1 deal with *binary* data, not text... and there are various different ways of converting from text to binary.

What's the purpose here? Do you have to make the hash match what some *other* code produces? If so, find out what encoding that other code uses to convert text to binary. If it's only got to match *your* code, you have a free hand - I'd suggest using either UTF-8 or UTF-16, both of which are guaranteed to be present in Java, commonly available on other platforms for future options, and cover the whole of the Unicode character repertoire.

Comment: Idea is to store the hash code to a server, and when the user logins from different handsets, only hash is passed to the server. Thus the same hash should be produced across different OSes. Pardon my newbieness here, but it seems that this works only with pure ascii, is that true? Thus I assume I need to convert e.g. base64 first, then SHA to be compatible between platforms?

Comment: @perza: No, absolutely not. You just need some way of converting the text to binary consistently to start with - and using UTF-8 or UTF-16 would be appropriate. So long as you can make sure that the code on all handsets (and the server) uses the same encoding, it'll all be fine.

Comment: So I assume that the online hash generators can not handle unicode strings properly, and thus produce differing results. Ok, I believe that is a good enough answer :)

Comment: @perza: As per my first sentence, there's no "correct" here, so there's no sense of "properly". Some may be using an appropriate encoding, but others may not. Any encoding which can reliably encode all Unicode characters is reasonable - so two different schemes can both be equally valid, but give different results.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Online Hash Converters"?

If you calculated the SHA1 Hash of some Unicode-String there is no possibility to get the String back from the Hash. That is the key of a Hash-Function, its "one directional".

You can use another SHA implementatin and check if you get the same hash as result.

Comment: Perhaps the right phrase would be "online hash generator", like http://www.nitrxgen.net/hashgen/